# Como redimensionar miniaturas geradas pelo Uploadfy? ASP.NET c# MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, upload

Olá, gostaria de saber como redimensionar as miniaturas geradas pelo plugins jQuery Uploadfy. Como mostro no print abaixo, ele gera as miniaturas de acordo com o tamanho real das imagens, é uma boa prática redimensiona-las apenas na amostra ou redimensionar o arquivo em sí?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal seria você gerar um arquivo de miniatura além do upload original, em que haverá economia de dados. Na hora de carregar a imagem, você pode carregar um arquivo menor, que abre mais rápido, e usa o arquivo original somente quando for necessário.

Utilize o plugin NuGet ImageResizer:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/

Exemplo de uso:

### Model

```
public class ProductPicture
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductPictureID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String Thumbnail { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public ProductPicture() { }

    public ProductPicture(int _ProductID) {
        this.ProductID = _ProductID;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductPicture productpicture)
{
    // Original Image
    if (productpicture.File != null && productpicture.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(productpicture.File.FileName);

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(imagesDirectory), fileName);
        productpicture.File.SaveAs(path);
        productpicture.FileName = fileName;
        ModelState.Remove("FileName");

        // Thumbnails
        if (productpicture.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
                //The resizing settings can specify any of 30 commands.. See http://imageresizing.net for details.
                //Destination paths can have variables like <guid> and <ext>, or 
                //even a santizied version of the original filename, like <filename:A-Za-z0-9>
            ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(productpicture.File, 
                imagesDirectory + "/Thumbnails/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                                        "width=250;height=250;format=jpg;mode=pad"));
            i.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
            i.Build();
            productpicture.Thumbnail = i.FinalPath.Split('\\').Last();
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.ProductPictures.Add(productpicture);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código redimensiona a imagem por completo não? Eu queria saber um modo para que apenas mostre redimensionado quando ele termina o upload. Pois quando termina, elas ficam do tamanho original e o formulário que tem abaixo vai parar bem longe dali hehe

Comment: Repare que eu coloquei um campo chamado `Thumbnail` no `Model`. Ele é outro arquivo menor que o original, e é este arquivo que deve ser exibido.

Comment: Sim eu vi esta parte, porém, ainda assim não é o que eu quero, pois quero manter o tamanho original da imagem, somente mostrar na tela de upload (depois que ele enche a barra ele mostra a imagem, quando faz o upload) com um tamanho diferente do original.

Comment: Então, mas tá tudo ali. Onde tem `// Original Image` é a lógica que salva a imagem original. `// Thumbnails` é a lógica que gera a miniatura.

Comment: Sim mas sem este model ele já gera uma miniatura (só que é a imagem normal hehe)... entende?

Comment: Deixa eu melhorar a resposta.